# EXCEL VBA- Export Workbook to Password-Protected ZIP file

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anyway to modify Ron De Bruin's code to export the current workbook to a *password-protected* zip file.  I've looked around for quite some time, and can't figure out how to enable such an option.

Code is here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm

```
Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub

Sub Zip_ActiveWorkbook()


 Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
    Dim FileNameZip, FileNameXls
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileExtStr As String

    DefPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\"    '<< Change
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create date/time string and the temporary xl* and Zip file name
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls"
    Else
        Select Case ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx"
        Case 52: FileExtStr = ".xlsm"
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls"
        Case 50: FileExtStr = ".xlsb"
        Case Else: FileExtStr = "notknown"
        End Select
        If FileExtStr = "notknown" Then
            MsgBox "Sorry unknown file format"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

    FileNameZip = DefPath & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
    Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - Len(FileExtStr)) & strDate & ".zip"

    FileNameXls = DefPath & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
    Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - Len(FileExtStr)) & strDate & FileExtStr

    If Dir(FileNameZip) = "" And Dir(FileNameXls) = "" Then

        'Make copy of the activeworkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileNameXls

        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)

        'Copy the file in the compressed folder
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FileNameXls

        'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = 1
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Delete the temporary xls file
        Kill FileNameXls

        MsgBox "Your Backup is saved here: " & FileNameZip

    Else
        MsgBox "FileNameZip or/and FileNameXls exist"

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found an accepted answer for this on another site using 7Zip......

```
strDestFileName = "c:\temp\TestZipFile.zip"   
strSourceFileName = "c:\temp\test.pdf"   
str7ZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"   
strPassword = "MyPassword"   

strCommand = str7ZipPath & " -p" & strPassword & " a -tzip """ & strDestFileName & """ """ & strSourceFileName & """"
Shell strCommand
```

Comment: That link is not directly taking to problem

Comment: Amazing tip. Worked for me! Thanks!