# Mass Set Password on Multiple PDF Files

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word, vba

I have a batch of 700 pdf files which require me to password protect.

My files are prepared using MailMerge in Words to obtain data from Excel and input into 700 pages of fixed template den convert them into each single pdf file.

Am I able to password protect when I convert them to each single pdf file or am I able to use another method, for example, using Excel VBA to set the password for it?

I am able to extract all the file name already.

[image: Screenshot of the file name and password]

Appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: As pointed out in the *"answer"* provided by @Peh you'll need to use another program to password protect your files. If you want to create some sort of automation for that with VBA then you should make sure that this external program provides a VBA reference to access this program from Excel. Alternatively you can also put each file into a password protected ZIP file like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24529843/1153513

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXCEL VBA- Export Workbook to Password-Protected ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448766/excel-vba-export-workbook-to-password-protected-zip-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel or Word cannot export a password protected PDF file. That's not supported. You would need a 3ʳᵈ party program like *PDFCreator* for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot PEH for reply. Can you give us some more details of how using PDFCreator?

Comment: @YasserKhalil that's too broad to answer here, but there are many tutorials out there on Google how to create password protected PDF files with VBA and PDFCreator. These should be detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I already googled and installed PDFCteator it doesn't seem to work with newer versions .. It doesn't work for me

Comment: @YasserKhalil Well telling "*it doesn't seem to work*" is completely useless because it doesn't say anything meaningful. As I said this cannot be answered here in a comment. If you have a question ask a *new question* show the code you have tried in your question and tell which errors you get and in which line. Then ask a proper question to that code (reading [ask] might help). "*It doesn't work for me*" doesn't help us to understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here's the link [From Here](https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?185-Using-PDFCreator-with-security-options-set) and I have added reference of PDFCreator but still got error on this line
Dim pdfjob As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
That's all ..

Comment: I can only say: Read my last comment carefully again.